# jQuery find first parent with child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, jquery-selectors

How to find first parent element with nested child by text?

I need to check for each element with `"name"` class if it belongs to propper category with `"title"` class but the markup has the following structure:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Cars</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a>
      <div class="name">Dodge</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Food</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a>
      <div class="name">Apple</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The dilemma is that I can't apply just `.closest()` or `.prev()` methods.

So, I think I need to check if nested `"title"` element with it's text was the first upper element of a closest parent othervise I will grab redundant section with unrelated title.

```
$('.name').each(function() {
  if ( $(this).closest('.col:contains("Food")').length ) {
    $(this).css('color', 'red'); // doesn't work
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` is correct here, but it gets the parent of the `.name` element, whereas the `.col` which contains `Food` is the previous sibling, so you need to add a `prev()` call in there too, like this:

```js
$('.name').each(function() {
  if ($(this).closest('.col').prev('.col:contains("Food")').length) {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Cars</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a>
      <div class="name">Dodge</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Food</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a>
      <div class="name">Apple</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could invert the logic to find the `.col` which contains `Food` and retrieve the related `.name`. This removes the need for explicit loop and the `if` condition:

```js
$('.col:contains("Food")').next('.col').find('.name').css('color' , 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Cars</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a>
      <div class="name">Dodge</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Food</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a>
      <div class="name">Apple</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Next Adjacent](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) Selector (“prev + next”)

```js
$('.col:contains("Food") + .col .name').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Cars</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a>
      <div class="name">Dodge</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="title">
      <span>Food</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <a>
      <div class="name">Apple</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Can also be achieved with CSS alone.